# FIles doesnt save after Electrons Build - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, electron, save, electron-builder, node.js-fs

Title:
Issue with Saving PDF Files in Electron App After Build

Body of the Question:
Hey everyone, hope you're doing well!

I'm working on an Electron app and everything was great while I was running it through npm run start. I didn't encounter any issues until I began building the app, in both dev and non-dev modes. I'm unable to save anything to the path chosen by the user. I managed to save a file some time ago (can't recall what changes I made), but now, the saved PDF is corrupted and completely empty. Considering this, I moved the PDF saving code from my function into the main process as a buffer. Unfortunately, I encountered the same error again.

Running with npm run start without compiling = Everything works fine, no errors.

I've been trying for hours to find a solution. Thanks for your help!

```js
const { createInvoice } = require(path.join(__dirname, 'createInvoice.js'));

ipcMain.on('submitInvoiceForm', async (event, formData) => {
    const desktopPath = path.join(os.homedir(), 'Desktop'); // Path to the user's Desktop
    const defaultFilePath = path.join(desktopPath,`Quote_${formData.invoiceNumber}-${formData.clientName}.pdf`);

    const { filePath } = await dialog.showSaveDialog({
        title: 'Save Quote',
        defaultPath: defaultFilePath,
        buttonLabel: 'Save',
        filters: [{ name: 'PDF', extensions: ['pdf'] }]
    });

    if (filePath) {
        try {
            const pdfBuffer = await createInvoice(formData);
            fs.writeFileSync(filePath, pdfBuffer);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
});
```

```json
[{
  "name": "@kosprodutora/gerador-de-nota-kos",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Gerador de orçamento para KOS Produtora",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder",
    "debug-build": "electron-builder --dir --config.extraMetadata.main=main.js"
  },
  "pluginOptions": {
    "electronBuilder": {
      "nodeIntegration": true,
      "externals": [
        "pdfkit"
      ]
    }
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "G",
    "email": "admin@k.com"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.kosprodutora.geradordenotakos",
    "productName": "Gerador de Nota KOS",
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis",
      "icon": "icon.ico"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^20.3.12",
    "electron-builder": "^23.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "get-stream": "^6.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pdfkit": "^0.13.0"
  }
}]
```

my createinvoice

```js
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
const getStream = require('get-stream');

async function createInvoice(invoice) {
    const doc = new PDFDocument();

    generateHeader(doc);
    generateCustomerInformation(doc, invoice);
    generateInvoiceTable(doc, invoice);
    generateFooter(doc);

    doc.end();

    return await getStream.buffer(doc);
}

function generateHeader(doc) {
    doc.text("Header Text");
}

function generateCustomerInformation(doc, invoice) {
    doc.text("Customer Information");
}

function generateInvoiceTable(doc, invoice) {
    doc.text("Invoice Table");
}

function generateFooter(doc) {
    doc.text("Footer Text");
}

module.exports = {
    createInvoice
};
```

A solutution for my problem.